# can't double-click to run appimage

Tags: plasma, ubuntu-studio, appimage

Ubuntu Studio 20.10 (Plasma). When I try to double-click either of the two appimage files I use, I get a "For security reasons, launching executables is not allowed in this context" window. The files are in my home directory, permissions are RWX for owner and group, and R-X for all.

I CAN run them by right-clicking and selecting run in Konsole. I can continue to do that, but I was wondering if there's a way to them behave like any other app on the system.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? 18 didn't have this issue.